# Seeking regex for HTML attributes meeting specific criteria

Tags: php, html, regex

I'm trying to remove single quotes and double quotes around HTML attributes with the following restrictions:

1) The quoted material MUST exist *within* a tag `<>` (e.g., `<mytag b="yes">` becomes `<mytag b=yes>`, but `<script>var b="yes"</script>` stays intact).

2) The quoted material may not have a space character nor an equal sign (e.g., `<mytag b="no no" c="no=no">` stays intact).

3) The quoted material may not be in an `href` or `src` definition.

4) The regex should be good for UTF-8 (duh!)

Someone posted a virtually identical question here that received an answer that works within the confines of the question:

[Removing single and double quote from html attributes with no white spaces on all attributes except href and src](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23587701/removing-single-and-double-quote-from-html-attributes-with-no-white-spaces-on-al)

So:

`((\S)+\s*(?<!href)(?<!src)(=)\s*)(\"|\')(\S+)(\"|\')`

...works, except it fails to isolate text within tags (i.e., text in between opening and closing tags is erroneously edited, e.g. `<mytag>"The quotes are stripped out here!"</mytag>`), and it doesn't check for equal signs (=) within the quoted text (e.g. `<mytag b="OhNo=TheRoutineRemovedTheQuotesBecauseItDidNotCheckForAnEqualSignInTheQuotedText!">`).

Bonus points: I wish to integrate this into this php HTML minification routine, which works well except for the edits described above:

https://gist.github.com/tovic/d7b310dea3b33e4732c0

His solution pairs the patterns and replacement params in two arrays, as you'll see, so I need to conform to his syntax, which uses `#`, etc.

Your solution get my upvote!

Comment: This seems like a bad idea. You should try using an HTML parser instead.

Comment: You'd be better off using a [`DocumentFragment`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/DocumentFragment)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a pure regex way of getting rid of the quotes:

```
'~(?:<\w+|(?!^)\G)(?:\s+(?:src|href)=(?:"[^"]*"|'[^']*'))*\s+(?!(?:href|src)=)\w+=\K(?|"([^\s"=]*)"|'([^\s'=]*)')~u'
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/nX9bS5/2), replace with '$1'.

[IDEONE demo](https://ideone.com/6zJIim):

```
$re = '~(?:<\w+|(?!^)\G)(?:\s+(?:src|href)=(?:"[^"]*"|\'[^\']*\'))*\s+(?!(?:href|src)=)\w+=\K(?|"([^\s"=]*)"|\'([^\s\'=]*)\')~u';
$str = "<mytag src=\"src_here\" b=\"yes\" href=\"href_here\"> becomes <mytag src=\"src_here\" b=yes href=\"href_here\">\n<mytag b='yes'> becomes <mytag b=yes>\nbut <script>var b=\"yes\"</script> stays intact\n<mytag b=\"no no\" c=\"no=no\"> stays intact\n<tag href=\"something\"> text <tag src=\"dddd\"> intact"; 
$subst = "$1"; 
$result = preg_replace($re, $subst, $str);
echo $result;
```

Pattern details:

- `(?:<\w+|(?!^)\G)` - match the tag (`<\w+`) or (`|`) the end of the last successful match (`(?!^)\G`)
- `(?:\s+(?:src|href)=(?:"[^"]*"|\'[^\']*\'))*` - matches the unwelcome `href` and `src` attributes to later omit them with `\K`
- `\s+` - match 1+ whitespace(s)
- `(?!(?:href|src)=)\w+=` - 1+ alphanumeric or underscore characters (`\w+`) followed with `=` that are not `href=` or `src=` (see `(?!(?:href|src)=)` negative lookahead)
- `\K` - omit the whole text matched so far
- `(?|"([^\s"=]*)"|\'([^\s\'=]*)\')` - a branch reset group capturing into Group 1 either:

  - `"([^\s"=]*)"` - double quoted attribute with no `=`, `'` and whitespace
  - `|` - or
  - `\'([^\s\'=]*)\'` - single quoted attribute with no `=`, `'` and whitespace

Comment: Thanks! This works on my initial testing of it. And I appreciate your clear explanation of the components of the regex!

Comment: I replied too soon...it seems that once "src" or "href" is encountered in a tag, all subsequent elements in that tag are ignored. Try putting `<img test="xxx" href="http://example.com/images/Vögel.jpg" alt="Vögel" height="100" width="100">
<img test="xxx" src="http://example.com/images/Vögel.jpg" alt="Vögel" height="100" width="100">` into your regex demo and you'll see.

Comment: You may match them before omitting with `\K`: [`(?:<\w+|(?!^)\G)(?:\s+(?:src|href)=(?:"[^"]*"|'[^']*'))*\s+(?!(?:href|src)=)\w+=\K(?|"([^\s"=]*)"|'([^\s'=]*)')`](https://regex101.com/r/nX9bS5/2). I updated the regex, demos and explanation.

Comment: Thanks! But I discovered a wrinkle: If the element has a hyphen in it, then it fails to recognize it as a tag element, and it and the subsequent attribute definitions are ignored; curiously, it's fine with underscores (_). Try: `<img test-time="xxx" src="http://example.com/images/Vögel.jpg" alt="Vögel" height="100" width="100">
<img test_time="xxx" src="http://example.com/images/Vögel.jpg" alt="Vögel" height="100" width="100">`

Comment: What convention do you need the regex to follow? If attribute names can include dots, hyphens or colons, let's include them and do the same for tag names: [`'~(?:<[a-z][\w:.-]*|(?!^)\G)(?:\s+(?:src|href)=(?:"[^"]*"|\'[^\']*\'))*\s+(?!(?:href|src)=)[a-z][\w:.-]*=\K(?|"([^\s"=]*)"|\'([^\s\'=]*)\')~ui'`](https://regex101.com/r/nX9bS5/3)

Comment: I'm using a third-party library that has custom elements that include hyphens in their names, sadly. But your revision almost gets it...but see this example: `<img aa-bb="xxx" cc-dd="xxx yyy" src="http://example.com/Vögel.jpg" temp="Bird" alt="The Bird" height="100" width="100">` For some reason in this example, it ceases editing out the quotes after the `src` element is encountered, perhaps because the elements with hyphenated names are encountered previously within the tag?

Comment: I believe that once it's found an element with a space or similar that requires it to retain the surrounding quotes, it ceases editing the attributes that follow for the rest of the tag.

Comment: Aha! It simply needs a `*` after the initial pattern, like this: `~(?:<[a-z][\w:.-]*|(?!^)\G)*`. Thus the complete solution is `~(?:<\w+|(?!^)\G)*(?:\s+(?:src|href)=(?:"[^"]*"|\'[^\']*\'))*\s+(?!(?:href|src)=)\w+=\K(?|"([^\s"=]*)"|\'([^\s\'=]*)\')~u` I owe you a beer :-)

Comment: I think what you did is incorrect. I will check once my kids go to bed.

Comment: It is rather unweildly, but this is what you have to pay for with such complex requirements: [`(?:<[a-z][\w:.-]*|(?!^)\G)(?:\s+(?:(?:src|href)=(?:"[^"]*"|'[^']*')|[a-z][\w:.-]*="(?:[^"=]*\s[^"=]*|[^"\s]*=[^"\s]*)"))*\s+(?!(?:href|src)=)[a-z][\w:.-]*=\K(?|"([^\s"=]*)"|'([^\s'=]*)')`](https://regex101.com/r/nX9bS5/4). All exceptions must be matched in the same branch with `\G`.

Comment: This is fantastic. I owe you several beers.

Comment: I hate to chime in 8 months later with an additional request, but I'm now dealing with meta tags with content definitions. As with other tags, no space characters ( ) or equal signs (=) means that that the surrounding quotes may be stripped, but their presence means that the quotes must be left intact. But here's the wrinkle: if the definition begins with http:// or https://, then I need to retain the surrounding quotes. I've been trying to edit the regex above to accomplish this for several hours, but I'm coming up dry. Can you see an easy fix? Many thanks in advance.

Comment: Please provide some test cases showing what you need to do.

Comment: I think we're in luck, as it turns out that the forward slash character in a property value is grounds for the value to remain in quotes (double or single). Thus, both content="image/jpeg" and src="https://example.com" would retain their surrounding quotes, as all that needs to be checked for is the presence of a forward slash, which occurs in both. Also, the presence of a comma requires the value to retain its quotes as in content="noindex,nofollow". See before and after below; perhaps just the forward slash and the comma should be added to the list of characters to be searched for:

Comment: `code<!-- Before minification: -->
    <meta property="og:type" content="website">
    <meta itemprop="description" content="Original Creations of Mine">
    <meta property="og:url" content="https://example.com">
    <meta property="og:image:type" content="image/jpeg">
    <meta name="robots" content="noindex,nofollow">
    <link rel="canonical" href="https://example.com">
    <link href="https://example.com/favicon.2012838.ico" rel="icon">`

Comment: Here: `<!-- After minification: -->
<meta property=og:type content=website>
<meta itemprop=description content="Original Creations of Mine">
<meta property=og:url content="https://example.com">
<meta property=og:image:type content="image/jpeg">
<meta name=robots content="noindex,nofollow">
<link rel=canonical href="https://example.com">
<link href="https://example.com/favicon.2012838.ico" rel=icon>`

Comment: Try [`(?:<[a-z][\w:.-]*|(?!^)\G)\s+(?:(?:href|src)=(['"]).*?\1\K|[a-z][\w.:-]*=(['"])https?:\/\/.*?\2\K|[a-z][\w:.-]*=\K(?|"([^\s"\/,=]*)"|'([^\s'\/,=]*)'))`](https://regex101.com/r/nX9bS5/5) to replace with `$3`.

Comment: Thanks, but there are apparently unescaped single quotes and other characters that don't allow the php to be read (even though it works fine as-is in the online regex tester.); my editor stops showing it as valid PHP code as soon as it encounters the "https" text (although the missing escapements may start earlier in the regex).

Answer (score 0):

Use this `(<[^=]*?(?<!href)(?<!src)=)"((\p{L}|\d)+)"(.*?>)` and replace 1st, 2nd and 4th capturing group with preg_replace while the replacements occure.

```
$a = '<aaa href="123ff" bbb="aaa">';
do {
  $b = preg_replace('/(<[^>]*?(?<!href)(?<!src)=)"((\\p{L}|\\d)+)"(.*?>)/u', '$1$2$4', $a, -1, $count);
  if(!$count) {
    break;
  }
  $a = $b;
}while(true);
```

Comment: Thanks, but this erroneously edits `<script>var b="yes"</script>`, as described in the first condition in my description. The loop suggests a long processing time.

Comment: I updated the regex. Now it should match things only in attributes.